# Why this simple image upload via PHP is not working

Tags: php, forms, file, file-upload

Hello I have 3 little multipart forms to upload 3 images

These is the HTML part (I have 3 times the same code):

```
<form method="post" action="?publishB&imageUploading1" enctype="multipart/form-data"><div class="fileUpload btn btn-primary"><span><strong>Cargar</strong></span><input type="file" name="imagen1" id="imagen1" class="uploadBotonGen" ></div><input type="submit" class="subirLaImagen" value="Publicar"></form>
```

This looks good to me!

And the PHP code is this one:

```
//                  IMAGEN 1

                    if(isset($_GET['imageUploading1']))
                    {


                                $imageName = addslashes($_FILE['imagen1']['name']);
                                $imageTempName =  $_FILE['imagen1']['tmp_name'];
                                $imageBlob = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILE['imagen1']['tmp_name']) );
                                $imageSize = getimagesize($_FILE['imagen1']['size']) ;

                                if($imageSize==FALSE)
                                    {
                                        $errorFileType=$i;
                                        echo "a";
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {


                                         try                   
                                        {   
                                            $pdo_options[PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE] = PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION;
                                            $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=lacajota', 'root', '', $pdo_options);

                                            $req = $bdd->prepare('INSERT INTO imagenes(userID, articID, name, image) VALUES(:userID, :articID, :name, :image)');
                                            $req->execute(array(

                                            'userID'=> $_SESSION['userID'],
                                            'articID'=> $LastArtLast['ID'],
                                            'name'=> $imageName,
                                            'image'=> $imageBlob
                                             ));


                                        }
                                        catch(Exception $e)
                                        {   
                                            die('Error:' . $e->getMessage());
                                        }


                                    }           

                    }
```

The server returns me the followinf error:

**Notice: Undefined variable: _FILE in C:\wamp\www\La Cajota\publish\index.php on line 182**

looks like the file is not well recive by my PHP code! The first error come at the first line (`$imageName = addslashes($_FILE['imagen1']['name']);`)

Thank you!

And yes this code is repeated 3 times, one for each upload form!

Answer (score 1):

Use `$_FILES`

$_FILE is not defined

check this link http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php